# Parsing a text log file to extract some fields of data from log messages

Tags: python, whitespace, formatting

I am new to python and stuck on how to do that.
I have a very large text file about 4GB contains error messages .Each message line in the text file represents one message, i need to filter out several columns and replace the space character with |.
Example:

```
input:
83b14af0-949b-71e0-18d5-0ad781020000 40ba8352-8dd2-71dc-12b8-0ad781020000 1 -1407714483 20 COLG-GRA-617-RD1.oss 1 181895426 12 oss-ap-1.oss 0 0 48 0 0 0 1307845644 1307845647 0 2 12 0 0 0  0 0 12 0 0 0  0 0 1307845918 3 OpC 6 opcecm 9 SNMPTraps 8 IBB_COLG 4 ATM0 0  0  0  69 Cisco Agent Interface Up (linkUp Trap) on interface ATM0 --Sev Normal 372 Generic: 3; Specific: 0; Enterprise: .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.569;
output:
83b14af0-949b-71e0-18d5-0ad781020000 | 40ba8352-8dd2-71dc-12b8-0ad781020000 | COLG-GRA-617-RD1.oss | 1307845644 | 1307845647 |1307845918 | Cisco Agent Interface Up (linkUp Trap) on interface ATM0 | Normal 372 | Generic: 3 | Specific: 0 | Enterprise: .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.569
```

Really I appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: When input is mapped to output no logical conversion is evident. How is your input mapped to your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file format is annoying.  We could split the input on white space, but some of the fields you want to capture should contain white space.  We could split the input on column numbers, but I am not certain that every string is always the same length; it seems likely that the numbers will vary in number of digits.  So the best solution should involve regular expressions.

A single regular expression to parse this whole line would be pretty mind-numbing to write and to understand.  But we can build up the pattern from shorter patterns.  I think the result is pretty easy to understand.  Also, if the file format changes or the fields you want to capture ever change, I think you can pretty easily change this.

Note that we use the Python "string repetition" operator, `*`, to repeat the shorter patterns.  If we have 2 words we want to recognize and capture, we can use `c*2` to repeat the capture pattern twice.

In your example of the desired output, you had some extra white space.  I wrote the patterns to not capture any white space, but if you actually want the white space you can edit the patterns as you like.

If you don't know about regular expressions, you should read the documentation for the Python `re` module.  Briefly, the part of the pattern enclosed in parentheses will be captured, and other parts will match but not be captured.  `\s` matches white space, and `\S` matches non-white space.  `+` in a pattern means "1 or more" and `*` means "0 or more".  `^` and `$` match beginning and end of the pattern, respectively.

```
import re

# Define patterns we want to recognize.

c = r'(\S+)\s+'  # a word we want to capture
s = r'\S+\s+'  # a word we want to skip
mesg = r'(\S.*\S)\s+--Sev\s+'  # mesg to capture; terminated by string '--Sev'
w2 = r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s+'  # two words separated by some white space
w2semi = r'(\S+\s+\S+)\s*;\s+'  # two words terminated by a semicolon
tail = r'(.*\S)\s*;'

# Join together the above patterns to make one giant pattern that parses
# the input.
s_pat = ( r'^\s*' + 
    c*2 + s*3 + c*1 + s*10 + c*2 + s*14 + c*1 + s*14 +
    mesg + w2 + w2semi*2 + tail +
    r'\s*$')

# Pre-compile the pattern for speed.
pat = re.compile(s_pat)

# Test string and the expected output result.
s_input = "83b14af0-949b-71e0-18d5-0ad781020000 40ba8352-8dd2-71dc-12b8-0ad781020000 1 -1407714483 20 COLG-GRA-617-RD1.oss 1 181895426 12 oss-ap-1.oss 0 0 48 0 0 0 1307845644 1307845647 0 2 12 0 0 0  0 0 12 0 0 0  0 0 1307845918 3 OpC 6 opcecm 9 SNMPTraps 8 IBB_COLG 4 ATM0 0  0  0  69 Cisco Agent Interface Up (linkUp Trap) on interface ATM0 --Sev Normal 372 Generic: 3; Specific: 0; Enterprise: .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.569;"
s_correct = "83b14af0-949b-71e0-18d5-0ad781020000|40ba8352-8dd2-71dc-12b8-0ad781020000|COLG-GRA-617-RD1.oss|1307845644|1307845647|1307845918|Cisco Agent Interface Up (linkUp Trap) on interface ATM0|Normal 372|Generic: 3|Specific: 0|Enterprise: .1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.569"

# re.match() returns a "match group"
m = re.match(pat, s_input)
# m.groups() returns sequence of captured strings; join with '|'
s_output = '|'.join(m.groups())

# sanity check
if s_correct == s_output:
    print "excellent"
else:
    print "bogus"

# excellent.
```

With the pattern written, tested, and debugged, it's very simple to write the program to actually process the file.

```
# use the pattern defined above, named "pat"
with open(input_file, "r") as f_in, open(output_file, "w") as f_out:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(f_in, 1):
        try:
            m = re.match(pat, line)
            s_output = '|'.join(m.groups())
            f_out.write(s_output + '\n')
        except Exception:
            print("unable to parse line %d: %s" % (line_num, line)
```

This will read the file one line at a time, process the line, and write the processed line to the output file.

Note that I'm using multiple `with` statements on one line.  This works with any recent Python but doesn't work on 2.5 or 3.0.

Comment: Thank you very very much, this is what i want, but when I applied this code to my file I received this error, I don not know why.

Comment: s_input=infile.readlines() 
ValueError: Mixing iteration and read methods would lose data

Comment: infile=open('test.txt', "r") 
outfile=open('output.txt', "w")
for line in infile:
 s_input=infile.readlines() 
 m = re.match(pat, s_input)
 s_output = '|'.join(m.groups())
 outfile.write(s_output + '\n')

Comment: There was a mistake in my example code.  I have edited it.  You can just say `for line in infile:` and the `for` loop will pull one line at a time from the open input file.  Do not call `infile.readlines()` because that will read the entire 4 GB file into memory all at once.

Comment: Now that I edited it, the for loop sets the variable `line` to the input line, and then `re.match()` is called with `line`.  If you prefer, you could use `s_input` instead of `line`; it doesn't matter what the variable name is as long as it matches.

Comment: Thank you very much, But I have made the same thing before for a large file. The program is working good but when it finds a dismactch it exit and store only the previous matched ones. It did not continue to the end of the file. I received the following error when I run the programs. File "program4.py", line 41, in <module>
    s_output = ' | '.join(m.groups())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Comment: So wrap it in a try block and catch any exceptions.  Or, you could just test to see whether `m is None`, which it will be if the pattern fails to match.  I have edited my answer to add a try block.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `replace()` method of a string for the line that you read in.  See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods for a list of string methods.

```
new_string = my_string.replace(' ', ' | ')
```

If you're needing to remove "columns" as well, you'll have more luck splitting your string first, eliminating the columns with "[slices](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)" and then joining the list on your splitter.

```
cols = my_string.split(' ')
cols = cols[:2] + cols[4:8] + cols[11:]  #Just making up some arbitrary removed columns
new_string = ' | '.join(cols)
```

Note this assumes your input will always be space separated and that your data does not contain spaces.  The splitting code gets a little more interesting if your input data is more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux, It is easy to replace characters using sed command. It will be faster than reading line by line in python, because your file is too big.

```
sed -i 's/pattern/|/g' inputfile
```

Above command will replace all pattern string with |.

Comment: Reading line by line in Python is perfectly fast; it doesn't matter how big the file is.  It would matter if the lines were very, very long, but in this case they are not.  And the parsing needed for this problem is complicated enough that `sed` is not a good choice.